# Is there a way to find the usages of a property that is bound to a WPF view?

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application that uses Caliburn.Micro to wire up the bindings by the x:name convention.  I also have Resharper installed on my dev boxes.  Normally Resharper identifies where properties are being used but all the properties that are only bound to the Views show up as unused and the 'Navigate to Usages of Symbol' is unable to find where I use it in my views.  I understand that this is probably because the bindings are created at runtime, but is there a tool out there that can fill this gap?  Ideally a resharper plugin?  Shouldn't this be easier to accomplish with Rosyln now that it is out?

Just for clarification, all of this works as it should, I am just looking for an easier way to navigate through my code base.

Comment: use find all with regex :) search for {Binding * Propertyname}

Comment: It's sad, because a find all is my current go to solution for this problem.

Comment: Also...obligatory "Then I would have 2 problems".

Comment: Resharper is already installed.